# Windows Firewall Annoyance

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

I dont know why , but my firewall isnt letting anything except for internet explorer connect to the internet, including Windows updates. Whenever I try to open the firewall, it simply says " Due to an unidentified problem, Windows cannot display Windows Firewall settings." Can anyone help?

Comment: windows xp? vista? 7? 8?

Comment: did you have a virus? Have you checked recently?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to control panel home in your computer and turn off temporary your firewall if you want to update your windows.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://superuser.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.